# "TwitterConnect is not defined" in cordova project

Tags: javascript, cordova, twitter, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to use twitter-connect-plugin on cordova project but this is what I'm getting

```
 Exception: TwitterConnect is not defined
```

this is javascript code

```
$("#btnTwitter").on("click", function () {
            TwitterConnect.login(function (data) {
                var accessToken = data.token;


            }, function (error) {
                console.log('Error in Login');
            });
        });
```

and this is the config

```
    <preference name="TwitterConsumerKey" value="" />
    <preference name="TwitterConsumerSecret" value="" />
    <plugin name="twitter-connect-plugin" version="0.6.0" src="https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/twitter-connect-plugin">
      <variable name="FABRIC_KEY" value="" />
    </plugin>
```

any help

Answer (score 1):

problem solved by deleting the `platforms` folder and rebuild the project